# How to close the popup window which appears during file downloads

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

In my implementation of the IDownloadHandler interface i have the following in OnDownloadUpdated. The window stays open??

```
            If downloadItem.IsComplete Or downloadItem.IsCancelled Then
                browser.CloseBrowser(True)
                browser.Dispose()
            End If
```

Must I have this popup window when a download is happening? I have read here I do, if yes how do I close it. I really thought I read in the project issues/comments that the default was now to automatically close it.

Comment: The example in https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/1033/files used to work.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment of amaitland (Thank you) I have my new window closing properly.

For the VB people - here is what I have added to the OnDownloadUpdated event

```
                If downloadItem.IsInProgress = False And browser.IsPopup And browser.HasDocument = False Then
                    browser.GetHost.CloseBrowser(False)
                    browser.GetHost.Dispose()
                End If
```